# How to create manual JSON in Oracle 18c?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I need to create manual json to send it as an input to a REST API. In past in 12c(v12.0.1.2), I was using APEX_JSON API and after doing some research found that Oracle 18c has

[Object Types in JSON](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plsql-object-types-for-json-12cr2)

I can't use SQL/PL_SQL functions as I need to create manual json. So can someone suggest where APEX_JSON is better or new API having `JSON_OBJECT_T`, `JSON_ARRAY_T`, `etc` are better in terms of performance and parsing?

Here is my sample JSON which I need to create. In this JSON only `routeStops` array can be accessed from Database and will have multiple stops based on the number of records but other than that other values are single in entire json and need to be hard coded values? So now please suggest can I achieve this with SQL functions?

```
"routeProfile": {
        "resourceProfileRef": "7T5FRANBSC",
        "driverRef": "",
        "vehicleRef": "",
        "dutyStartTime": "10:30",
        "dutyDurationHours": 0,
        "startLocation": {
            "knownLocationRef": "",
            "houseName": "",
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "address3": "",
            "address4": "",
            "postCode": "",
            "countryCode": "",
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [-999,
                    -999],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        },
        "mandatoryFirstStop": false,
        "mandatoryFirstStopLocation": {
            "knownLocationRef": "",
            "houseName": "",
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "address3": "",
            "address4": "",
            "postCode": "",
            "countryCode": "",
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [-999,
                    -999],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        },
        "mandatoryFirstStopTime": 0,
        "mandatoryLastStop": false,
        "mandatoryLastStopLocation": {
            "knownLocationRef": "",
            "houseName": "",
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "address3": "",
            "address4": "",
            "postCode": "",
            "countryCode": "",
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [-999,
                    -999],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        },
        "mandatoryLastStopTime": 0,
        "endLocation": {
            "knownLocationRef": "",
            "houseName": "",
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "address3": "",
            "address4": "",
            "postCode": "",
            "countryCode": "",
            "countryCode": "",
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [-999,
                    -999],
                "type": "Point"
            }
        }
    },
    "routeStops": [{
            "stop": 1,
            "location": {
                "knownLocationRef": "",
                "houseNumber": "",
                "houseName": "Shop XYZ",
                "address1": "Ruddington Lane",
                "address2": "Wilford",
                "address3": "Nottingham",
                "address4": "",
                "postCode": "NG11 7DQ",
                "countryCode": "GB",
                "location": {
                    "coordinates": [-999,
                        -999],
                    "type": "Point"
                }
            },
            "jobs": [{
                    "jobRef": "3735081",
                    "jobTypeRef": "STDSTOPJOB",
                    "customer": {
                        "title": "",
                        "initials": "",
                        "firstName": "",
                        "lastName": "",
                        "homePhone": "",
                        "workPhone": "",
                        "mobilePhone": "",
                        "email": ""
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "knownLocationRef": "",
                        "houseNumber": "",
                        "houseName": "Shop XYZ",
                        "address1": "Ruddington Lane",
                        "address2": "Wilford",
                        "address3": "Nottingham",
                        "address4": "",
                        "postCode": "NG11 7DQ",
                        "countryCode": "GB",
                        "location": {
                            "coordinates": [-999,
                                -999],
                            "type": "Point"
                        }
                    },
                    "customerAccountRef": "CUSTACC001",
                    "jobScheduling": {
                        "schedulingDateTimeEarliest": "2018-12-21 00:00",
                        "schedulingDateTimeLatest": "2018-12-21 23:59",
                        "excludeDateTimeEarliest": "2018-12-21 12:00",
                        "excludeDateTimeLatest": "2018-12-21 13:00"
                    }
                }]
            }]
```

Comment: Although what's better may be subjective, I believe `JSON_OBJECT_T` is definitely better as `APEX_JSON` is primarily designed for Apex module and the Oracle's new JSON API to construct JSONs starting 12.2 should definitely be designed to perform better across Oracle database application and not just for APEX module.

Comment: @KaushikNayak So, to create manual json in 18c, I need to use `JSON_OBJECT_T` right?

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting the data using SQL selects, you can use the JSON generation functions added in 12.2. These are:

- JSON_object
- JSON_objectagg
- JSON_array
- JSON_arrayagg

For example, the following creates an array of employee objects by department, using the standard HR schema:

```
select json_object (
         'department' value d.department_name,
         'employees' value json_arrayagg (
           json_object (
             'name' value first_name || ', ' || last_name, 
             'job' value job_title
       ))) DOC
from   hr.departments d, hr.employees e, hr.jobs j
where  d.department_id = e.department_id
and    e.job_id = j.job_id
and    d.department_id = 110
group  by d.department_name;

DOC   
{
  "department" : "Accounting",
  "employees" :
  [
    {
      "name" : "Shelley, Higgins",
      "job" : "Accounting Manager"
    },
    {
      "name" : "William, Gietz",
      "job" : "Public Accountant"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can find out more about these in the [JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A)

Comment: Thanks for this answer but what about if I want to create json manually?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar - I'm not sure what you mean by "manually". Where are you getting the data from? What makes the creation "manual"?

Comment: Manaul means I need to pass some harcoded values as per given format from the third party. In my case, I need to pass some values from tables and some harcoded values.

Comment: If you're getting some of the data from your database tables, the functions above are the way to go; you can include values from a third party in this

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Chirs I have added my sample JSON which I need to pass to third party web service.

Comment: Also, when I try to create large json I am getting error `ORA-40478 : too_large(maximum:4000)`

Comment: can you suggest which will be better in terms of performance? Query or PL/SQL, I have added sample json also now. Waiting for your update