# How to put empty string in JSON_OBJECT_T object?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracle18c

I am trying to add an empty string to a `JSON_OBJECT_T` using the following code but I am getting `null` in value and not empty string.

```
DECLARE
   V_OBJ JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
   V_OBJ := JSON_OBJECT_T();
   V_OBJ.PUT('customerAccRef','');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_OBJ.stringify);
END;
```

When I do this, I am getting the following json

```
{"customerAccRef":null}
```

and I want output as below

```
{"customerAccRef":""}
```

Can someone suggest what change I need to do to pass an empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is happening is due to the fact that Oracle internally changes empty string to `NULL` values. It is due to some legacy reason and you may read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203536/7998591) to know the history.

I couldn't find anywhere in the JSON documentation with an option to bypass this particular problem myself, although I'd be glad if someone could find it.

As a workaround to your problem, you could use `TRIM` function to convert a single space to blank string.

```
V_OBJ.PUT('customerAccRef' , TRIM(' '));
```

which gives

```
{"customerAccRef":""}
```

This seems to work both in Oracle 12.2 version; I tested in my local machine and in Oracle 
18c : [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46df35ce86ba87d566d029628ea875dd),   as well as in  [**19c (LiveSQL online)**](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/h685vtb35l67w5gpwe9v3noie)

A point to also note here is that a simple `select TRIM(' ') from dual` always returns `NULL`, which is surprising and luckily for you, it works as expected with JSONs

Comment: Thanks, I thought of the same but was checking whether I could do without calling any function? Also do you have any suggestion for my other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644055/how-to-create-manual-json-in-oracle-18c

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar : I'm sorry.I don't think I can ever answer Oracle JSON related question (or any SQL for that matter) which Chris Saxon couldn't (and he didn't answer it yet after you adding details in the question ).  You may ask a new question linking the previous one with the required detail and may be he or somebody else could help you. Regarding this particular question, its upto you whether you want to wait for other answers ( may be Chris himself can, without using `TRIM`) or go ahead with this.

Comment: I used the workaround provided by you and its working fine. Thanks Also, if you can suggest anything for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535454/how-to-parse-json-efficiently-in-oracle-18c, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

In 19c, using `put(..., '')` you get an empty string.
Using `put_null`, or `put(..., to_char(null))`, `put(..., <unitializedString>)` you get the "real" null value.

```
DECLARE
   V_OBJ JSON_OBJECT_T;
   V_STRING VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   V_OBJ := JSON_OBJECT_T();
   V_OBJ.PUT('doubleSingleQuotes','');
   V_OBJ.PUT('toCharNull',to_char(null));
   V_OBJ.PUT('uninitializedStringVariable',v_string);
   V_OBJ.PUT_null('null');
   V_OBJ.PUT('trimSpace', trim(' '));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_OBJ.stringify);
END;
```

... gives :

```
{"doubleSingleQuotes":"","toCharNull":null,"uninitializedStringVariable":null,"null":null,"trimSpace":""}
```