# How to parse json efficiently in Oracle 18c?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracle18c

I am trying to parse a large json using `JSON_OBJECT_T`, `JSON_ARRAY_T` APIs and its working fine but I want expert suggestions whether it is efficient or not?

I am adding my json file and parsing code as below

[SampleJson](https://filebin.net/361xflv8vvd4qifp/GetOutput.json?t=8g1ypmsl)

**Code**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   l_clob clob;
   l_time timestamp;

   l_json json_object_t;
   l_stops_array json_array_t;
   l_stops_arr json_array_t;

   routeInfoObj json_object_t;
   routeStopArr json_array_t;
BEGIN
   SELECT LOG_CLOB INTO l_clob FROM ITV_DEV_LOGS WHERE LOG_ID = 1435334;
   l_time := systimestamp;

   l_json := json_object_t.parse( l_clob );

   dbms_output.put_line( 'Parsing Time: ' || extract(second from( systimestamp - l_time ) ) );
   l_stops_array := l_json.get_array('data');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data array: '||l_stops_array.get_size);
   FOR i in 0..l_stops_array.get_size-1 loop
      l_stops_arr := TREAT(l_stops_array.get(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).get_array('routedStops');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('stops array: '||l_stops_arr.get_size);
      FOR j in 0..l_stops_arr.get_size - 1 loop
         routeInfoObj := TREAT(l_stops_arr.get(j) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).get_object('routingInfo');
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Stop : ' || routeInfoObj.get_number('stop'));
         routeStopArr := TREAT(l_stops_arr.get(j) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).get_array('routedJobs');
         FOR k in 0..routeStopArr.get_size - 1 loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('JobRef : ' || TREAT(routeStopArr.get(k) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).get_string('jobRef'));
         // update query to update stop value to respective jobRef
        end loop;
      end loop;
  end loop;
END;
```

It's working fine but is there a way to improve this implementation as this is just a sample json and count of objects inside may go to 2000 and instead of updating records one by one, is there a way to update all records in one statement?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to? Just print out the JSON? Or are you trying to insert the data into a normalized data model? If you are trying to update a table, how does that table look like? And which part of the JSON should go into that table?

Comment: Please provide a  simple  json which we can use to reduce this to a simpler problem. Also, tell us what you want to see as output rather then we trying to reverse engineer it from your code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to update ‘stop’ value in my sequence column and jobRef in json is my primary key which will help me to find the record.

Comment: @KaushikNayak the attached json is the exact one that I will receive and if I add a simple json then I would be giving you wrong information and I want to update sequence column with ‘stop’ value from json using jobRef value which is primary key in my table.

Comment: So you want to change the actual JSON, not some table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No I want to update column in my table with stop value from json and to do that jobRef will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json_table()` to turn the JSON value into a relational representation. That in turn can be used within a MERGE statement.

E.g. the following query:

```
select j.*
from itv_dev_logs
  cross join json_table(log_clob, '$.data.routedStops[*]'
                        columns stop_id integer path '$.stopId',
                                zone_ltf integer path '$.zoneLTF', 
                                info_stop_nr integer path '$.routingInfo.stop',
                                info_route_ref varchar(20) path '$.routingInfo.routeRef',
                                info_eta varchar(20) path '$.routingInfo.eta',
                                info_eta_dt timestamp path '$.routingInfo.etaDateTime',
                                info_stop_time number path '$.routingInfo.stopTime'
                        ) j
where log_id = 1435334;
```

Returns something like this:

```
STOP_ID       | ZONE_LTF | INFO_STOP_NR | INFO_ROUTE_REF | INFO_ETA | INFO_ETA_DT             | INFO_STOP_TIME | INFO_DIST_PREV_STOP | INFO_BREAK_TIME | INFO_BREAK_DURATION
--------------+----------+--------------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------
1554383571432 |        1 |            1 | R119           | 11:01    | 2019-04-16 11:01:00.000 |           0.08 |                0.27 | 00:00           | 00:00              
1554383571515 |        1 |            2 | R119           | 11:07    | 2019-04-16 11:07:00.000 |           0.08 |                0.34 | 00:00           | 00:00              
1554383571601 |        1 |            3 | R119           | 11:13    | 2019-04-16 11:13:00.000 |           0.08 |                   0 | 00:00           | 00:00              
1554383571671 |        1 |            4 | R119           | 11:19    | 2019-04-16 11:19:00.000 |           0.08 |                   0 | 00:00           | 00:00              
1554383571739 |        1 |            5 | R119           | 11:25    | 2019-04-16 11:25:00.000 |           0.08 |                   0 | 00:00           | 00:00
```

---

That could be used as the source of a MERGE statement to update your target table:

```
merge into your_target_table tg
using (
    select j.*
    from itv_dev_logs
      cross join json_table(log_clob, '$.data.routedStops[*]'
                            columns stop_id integer path '$.stopId',
                                    zone_ltf integer path '$.zoneLTF', 
                                    info_stop_nr integer path '$.routingInfo.stop',
                                    info_route_ref varchar(20) path '$.routingInfo.routeRef',
                                    info_eta varchar(20) path '$.routingInfo.eta',
                                    info_eta_dt timestamp path '$.routingInfo.etaDateTime',
                                    info_stop_time number path '$.routingInfo.stopTime'
                            ) j
    where log_id = 1435334
) t on (t.stop_id = tg.stop_id and ... more join conditions ...)
when matched then update
    set stop_nr = t.info_stop_nr, 
        eta_timestamp = t.eta_dt,
```

---

As you neither provided the structure of the target nor the information which JSON keys should be matched to which table columns, all column names are just guesses and you need to replace them with the correct names.

Comment: there are 2 columns in table, sequence and job_id. Sequence should be matched with routingInfo.stop and job_id is primary key of my table and need to be matched with routedJobs.jobRef. Also will JSON_TABLE improve performance?

Comment: Can you suggest whether JSON_TABLE() will improve performance as I may need to update 2000 records in some cases?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: a single MERGE statement will most likely be faster than 2000 update statements. But you need to test for yourself